# Prevent cgroup filesystem from getting mounted

Tags: 14.04, cgroup

On trusty, I installed `cgroup-lite` which mounts the virtual FS for cgroups subsystems in `/sys/fs/cgroup/*`. I've executed `cgclear` (from the `cgroup-bin` package) and uninstalled/purged `cgroup-lite`. When I reboot, the subsystems are mounted again. Question is: how can I prevent this from happening? Is there any config/script file that is read/executed when booting that accomplishes this?

No other packages related to cgroups (e.g. `lxc`, `libcgroup1` or `cgmanager`) are installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting help from the `cgroup-lite` maintainers at [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cgroup-lite/+bug/1480004), this turned out to be a problem with docker and not with `cgroup-lite` itself. Uninstalling docker leaves configuration files in `/etc/init` that mount the cgroup subsystems at boot time. So purging docker solves this problem.